# Verilog: Instantiation of lpm_dff failed. The design unit was not found

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, flipflop, rtl

I want to use `lpm_dff` components in my design. I can compile the code without problem in `modelsim`, But when i try to simulate my test bench i receive this error. I also add `lpm` library when i simulate the test bench.

Can someone help me fix the problem?

Comment: That sounds like a vendor-specific library part. Which vendor's tools are you using? Do you really need that part, or can you use something more generic?

Comment: Ensure you included this module's file into the project. While Quartus (you do not state which vendor you use) searches for appropriate modules if they are not in project, Modelsim may have  difficulties finding it.

Answer (score 1):

The Altera edition of ModelSim (including the free starter version) contains precompiled libraries for all of the Altera primitive IP cores (LPM cores, PLLs, RAMs, etc.). However in order to simulation with them you need to make sure you include the library that contains these parts.

- For general cores, they are all in the `altera_mf_ver` library (for Verilog) or `altera_mf` library (VHDL versions).
- For device specific parts like PLLs you would use the library for your device as well (e.g. `cyclonev_ver` is the Verilog library for Cyclone V devices).
- For the LPM cores I believe they are in the `lpm_ver` library (for Verilog) or `lpm` library (for VHDL), but may also be in `altera_mf_ver` as well..

How to include the library will depend on how you are running the simulation.

- If you are running it using the GUI (`Simulate -> Start Simulation`), simply select the required libraries in the `Search Libraries (-L)` box on the library tab of the start simulation screen.
- If you are using command line, you can append the switch `-L altera_mf_ver -L lpm_ver` to the end of your `vlog` command.